# Can a foreign key have a default value equal to 0?

Tags: foreign-key

I have a column whose default value is 0 .Can I make that column as foreign_key

Comment: Sure, as long as you have a row with the same value for the referenced column in the parent table.

Comment: I wonder if you don't mean that if the column has value 0, it should refer to nothing? In that case you shouldn't have a default but rather leave it null. This is called an "optional foreign key".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can define a column with a default value of 0 as a Foreign Key.  However, for the constraint to work, you would need to have a row in the source table with a value of 0 as well.  Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Master
(MasterID INT Primary Key,
 Name NVARCHAR(20));

INSERT into dbo.Master values (0,NULL);
INSERT into dbo.Master values (1,'Full');
INSERT into dbo.Master values (2,'Partial');

CREATE TABLE dbo.Slave
(SlaveID INT Primary Key,
 Description NVARCHAR(20),
 MasterID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Master(MasterID) DEFAULT (0));

 INSERT  INTO dbo.SLAVE (SlaveID, Description) VALUES(10,'Quickly');
```

This works fine.  However, what if Master does not have a 0 MasterID.  Then you would get:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 15
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Slave__MasterID__3943762B". 
The conflict occurred in database "TEST", table "dbo.Master", column 'MasterID'.
```

There is a `WITH NOCHECK` option (in SQL Server) which allows you to create a Foreign Key without the required data existing in the master table.  Likewise, Foreign Key constraints can be disabled and enabled, but I would recommend **against** doing that for any normal circumstances.  This is defined at:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score -2):

You can insert the 0 primary id record in the main table.